# Renderizar componentes de BLAZOR en un foreach

Tags: c#, blazor

Tengo un componente cualquiera, que siempre lo renderizo de la misma manera en el .razor, es decir, llamandolo como una "etiqueta" de html:

```
<Componente propiedad1="x" propiedad2="y"></Componente>
```

Ahora pretendo guardar una lista de esos componentes con sus propiedades asignadas en un objeto de tipo

```
List<Componente> Componentes = new List<Componente>();
```

Con lo cual, a primera instancia, lo primero que se viene a la cabeza para renderizarlos en el .razor sería hacer algo así:

```
foreach(Componente item in Componentes)
{
@item
}
```

Pero esto no funciona lógicamente. He estado buscando información y parece que hay que usar la clase RenderFragment, sin embargo no logro entender como usarla.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una solución obvia

```
@foreach (var item in Componentes)
{
    <Componente></Componente>
}
```

Y si tiene parametros los vas colocando, algo así:

```
@foreach (var item in Componentes)
{
    <Componente parametro1="item.parametro1" parametro2="item.parametro"></Componente>
}
```

Luego existe otra manera, usando `RenderFragment`. En ambos casos caes en lo mismo, que estas volviendo a crear un `Componente` a partir de los datos del primero, es decir lo estas duplicando no utilizando el original que está guardado en la lista.

Me parece (pero no puedo estar 100%) que no existe forma de hacer lo que tú quieres, esto es porque los componentes tienen un ciclo de vida el cual tú no puedes inicializar, entonces al instanciar un componente por código `new Componente()` no se da marcha a ese ciclo de vida.

Yo llevo utilizando bastante Blazor desde la Beta, y nunca he caído (ni me puedo imaginar) un escenario valido para lo que estas solicitando.

En esa lista de `Componentes` no deberías guardar el componente entero, deberías guardar los datos que contiene ese componente. Guardar el componente entero es un uso de recursos innecesario y además como puedes ver en tu caso se hace todo más complejo.

Un ejemplo análogo podría ser que al querer respaldar una base de datos, guardar el motor entero con .exe, .dll y todo, en vez de solo guardar el backup de las tablas.

**¿Entonces como lo haría?**

Supongamos un componente llamado `Componente` que recibe como paramentro una clase llamada `UnaClase`, donde en esta última tengo todos los datos que dan vida al componente.

```
public class UnaClase
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

```
<h3>@unaclase.Texto</h3>
@code {
//COMPONENTE

    [Parameter]
    public UnaClase unaclase { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Luego puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
@foreach (var item in Datos)
{
    <Componente unaclase="item" ></Componente>
}

@code{
    public List<UnaClase> Datos { get; set; } = new List<UnaClase>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Datos.Add(new UnaClase()
            {
                Texto = i.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
```